# Best way to use class methods in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I wanted to get opinions on the "best" way of using class methods in PHP.

I've always believed this is the better way:

```
class Customer {
    public $customer_id;
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function __construct( $defaults = array() ) {
        foreach ( $defaults as $key => $value ) {
            if ( property_exists( $this, $key ) ) {
                $this->{ $key } = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    public function get( $customer_id ) {

        $row = ... // Get customer details from database
        if ( $row ) {
            $this->customer_id = $customer_id;
            $this->name = $row['name'];
            $this->email = $row['email'];
        else {
           throw new Exception( 'Could not find customer' );
        }

        // Don't return anything, everything is set within $this

    }

    public function update() {

        // No arguments required, everything is contained within $this

        if ( ! $this->customer_id ) {
            throw new Exception( 'No customer to update' );
        }
        ... // Update customer details in the database using 
            // $this->customer_id, 
            // $this->name and 
            // $this->email
    }
}
```

**Methodology #1.** The class would then be used like this:

```
$customer = new Customer();

// Get the customer with ID 123
$customer->get( 123 );

echo 'The customer email address was ' . $customer->email;

// Change the customer's email address
$customer->email = 'abc@zyx.com';
$customer->update();
```

**Methodology #2.** However, I see most CodeIgniter examples, and WordPress examples, use this type of methodology:

```
$customer = new Customer();

// Get the customer with ID 123
$cust = $customer->get( 123 );

echo 'The customer email address was ' . $cust->email;

$cust->email = 'abc@zyx.com';
$customer->update( array( 'customer_id' => 123, 'email' => $cust->email ) );
```

The second example involves the `get` method returning a copy of the object, and the `update` method requires arguments passing in rather than working with `$this`

I can't help feeling the first example is cleaner and better but perhaps I'm overlooking something?

PS: Please ignore the fact the above examples don't use namespaces, setters, getters, etc, I've trimmed them down to the minimum for illustrative purposes.

Comment: The second allows you to apply a fluent interface